# db2 jdbc driver does not release table locks

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, transactions, jndi

situation: We have a web service running on tomcat accessing DB2 database on AS400, we are using JTOPEN drivers for JNDI connections handled by tomcat. For handling transactions and access to database we are using Spring.

For each select system takes JDBC connection from JNDI (i.e. from connection pool), does selection, and in the end it closes ResultSet, Statement and releases Connection in that order. That passes fine, shared lock on table dissappears.

When we want to do update the same way as we did with select (exception on ResultSet object, we don't have one in such situation), after releasing Connection to JNDI lock on table stays.

If we put maxIdle=0 for number of connections in JNDI configuration, this problem disappears, but this degrades performances, we have cca 100 users online on that service, we need few connections to be alive in pool.

What do you suggest?

Comment: it seems that this problem is related to db2, and it is actually, a feature: http://archive.midrange.com/java400-l/201003/msg00028.html

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like as if the auto-commit is by default disabled and that the code isn't calling `connection.commit()` anywhere. To fix this, either configure the connection pool so that it only returns connections with `autoCommit = true`, or change the JDBC code that it commits the transaction at end of the `try` block wherein the SQL action is been taken place.

Comment: of course we did commit()-ed our transactions. We concluded that if we have combination of two transactions on the same table; one update and one select, both legally commit()-ed, only in that situation we got table left locked.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://wiki.midrange.com/index.php/SQL#IBM_Support_Document_18874457).

It helped me in the same case.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what exactly helped and keep the link for the reference. Have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).